# Why is Elixir faster than JRuby?

Tags: jvm, erlang, jruby, elixir, bytecode

I picked JRuby because it's similar to Elixir in a sense that they are both dynamic languages that are compiled into bytecode to be consumed by a VM.

If I understood correctly, since they are dynamic, the compiler doesn't have the necessary information to make the bytecode as efficient as their statically type counterparts.

Does it have to do anything with the fact that BEAM is a registered base VM while JVM is stack based?

Thanks :)

Comment: Your question's heading claims that jruby is slower, but do you actually have any measurements backing up that claim?

Answer (score 2):

Elixir is not faster than JRuby and JRuby is not faster than Elixir. There are many tasks where Elixir is faster than JRuby and there it is another way around. And as always it depends on many things. If you are talking about complex application web server, probably, but it is not about register or stack based VM but about lightweight processes and simplicity of Elixir based web stacks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Hynek, but what stops JRuby from achieving the same level of efficiency for complex app servers?

Comment: This is a good writeup: http://ds.cs.ut.ee/courses/course-files/To303nis%20Pool%20.pdf

tl;dr; Nothing really - except that Erlang's actor model combined with the way it handles processes (re: not mapped 1-to1 against OS-level threads) give it a boost for concurrency.

Comment: if you're talking about app servers then you have to consider that those are very complex programs that can easily differ in constant factors (or worse!) simply due to their implementation quality, independent of the executing runtime environment. it's very difficult to compare performance of a VM based on completely separate software running on top of the VM. It's like trying to compare vmware and xen performance by running mysql on one and postgres on the other.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the Elixir language is "less" dynamic as it were (or other qwirks that JRuby's authors had to work around/implement that slow down the runtime).

There are some suggestions for speeding it up:

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/PerformanceTuning

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Improving-startup-time

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Truffle